# Activity execution depending on another activity's dialog reponse

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Hello everybody and thanks in advance,

I call from activity one a dialog in activity two. The thing is that, code execution in activity one continues and don't wait for dialog response from activity two.

How can I make activity one wait for response of activity two's dialog and continue execution depending on the button pressed in dialog?

Thanks everybody for your time and attention!!

Comment: Do you  know `startActivityResult(...) ` in android ?

Comment: The question is not clear, explain it clearly

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I was about to suggest SharedPreferences but `startActivityResult()` is simpler.

Comment: But `startActivityForResult()` is intended for calling another activity if I'm not wrong, but I just calling a function from that activity which shows a dialog this way:     `FuncionesActivity Funciones = new FuncionesActivity();
Funciones.MuestraDialogo(this, TIPO_SALIR);`